# Application for query server status in LAN

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2012, local-area-network

I'm new in this category and I have a question. Is there an application that check server status(Down or UP) in a LAN that work in a Domain? for example every 1 hour check servers status.

Thanks

Comment: `Is there an application that check server status(Down or UP) in a LAN that work in a Domain?` - Yes, there's like a bazillion of them.

Comment: Can you mention some of them please? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are indeed tons of them. 
If you want a free and efficient monitoring solution, I would recommand Zabbix, it's pretty easy to set up, the documentation is well maintained, you can find a lot of templates in their share, and the community on the forum is pretty active.

Nagios is (was ?) a good monitoring solution, but it's really old now and the "newcomers" like Zabbix are way more efficient and scalable, easier to configure/manage, etc..

Answer (score 1):

You can use Nagios or Zabbix. In nagios is "ping check" , with this "plugin" you can check server up or down. In nagios/zabbix you can check other services example: MySQL, http/s.